# I want to change dimensions in a RasterStack file in R

Tags: r, resize, raster

I am not that experienced in programming, especially quite a newbie in R, and there may be easier and faster solutions to my problem. So here it goes

I have some jpegs that are stored in a list (IDlist) of RasterStack class objects. Some of them have pixel dimensions that exceed what I want (namely more than 2000 pixels in either width OR height). I would like to resize these pictures only, and resize them so that the dimension(s) exceeding 2000 pixels be maximum 2000. That being said, I plan to maintain the aspect ratio in each picture, so not crop out anything.

I am attaching a code block of my approach so far. The error occurs when I assign new values to the ncols and nrows:

- Error in nrow(imageList[[i]]) <- 2000 : could not find function "nrow<-"

My gut feeling tells me this may not be a good way at all but with my experience I cant grasp exacly why.

Afterwards I also want to have RasterStack format, so if any conversion is made I need to re-convert it.

Example image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ6QW.jpg)

Any input / opinion / comment is more than welcome.

```
for (i in 1:length(IDlist))
{
  a <- imageList[[i]]
  ratio <- ncol(a)/nrow(a)
  
  if (nrow(a) >= 2000 && nrow(a) >= ncol(a))
  {
    nrow(imageList[[i]]) <- 2000
    ncol(imageList[[i]]) <- ratio / nrow(a)
  }
  else if (ncol(a) >= 2000 && ncol(a) >= nrow(a))
  {
    ncol(imageList[[i]]) <- 2000
    nrow(imageList[[i]]) <- ncol(a) / ratio
  }
  rm(a)
  rm(ratio)
}
```

Comment: I think you want `dim()` or `extent()`. https://rdrr.io/cran/raster/man/dimensions.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994785/r-raster-change-image-size-keep-aspect-ratio-and-dpi-unchanged

Comment: Or resample! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55481898/error-after-changing-extentresolution-in-r. If you post example data (one or two image), I can demo, if you like.

Comment: Hey @Skaqqs! A friend is currently trying to help with conversion to magick files and then reducing the pixels, but there are some issues atm. I added an image and I am looking forward to your approach .